# How can I install files the maintainer has configured Bower to ignore?

Tags: three.js, bower

I'm using [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) and there are a number of useful files under the `examples/` directory that I wish to include in my project. Unfortunately, `examples/` is listed under the `ignore` property of the three.js `bower.json` [config file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/bower.json).

Is there a straightforward way to install specific files under `examples/` with Bower?

Answer (score 0):

Whole idea that is behind bower is to focus only on main library files.

From my point of view you have options:

1. use derivative package via npm instead of bower and in your code reference from `node_modules` directory - for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/three.js
2. create your own npm package based on npm/bower and use it the same way

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for your specific case.

1. Perhaps the easiest for your scenario is to install [threejs-examples](https://github.com/bodylabs/threejs-examples) using bower to get the examples directory. This is best used in combination with threejs-build to ensure consistent versions of threejs.

   ```
   bower install threejs-build threejs-examples
   ```
2. Alternatively you could install the whole git repository and copy out what you need (may take some time)

   ```
   bower install mrdoob/three.js
   ```
3. Or you could use a grunt task like [grunt-bower](https://github.com/curist/grunt-bower) which can install only the packages you require by using the packageSpecific and files options.

   The following grunt snippet will copy only orbit controls from the examples directory

   ```
   bower: {
       dev: {
           dest: 'components/',
           options: {
               packageSpecific: {
                   'threejs': {
                       files: [
                           'examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'
                       ]
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   },
   ```